# Condition for infinitely many solutions for non-homogeneous linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

In terms of ranks I know the system has a solution if and only if rank A=rank of augmented matrix, I know system has a unique solution if and only if rank A=rank of augmented matrix=n(no of columns of matrix A) but for infinitely many solutions what is the condition in terms of ranks of the matrix A and augmented matrix?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda\ne4$ or $\mu\ne0$, then $\text{rank}(A)=2$ and $\text{rank}(A|b)=2$

$\;\;\;$since both matrices have 2 linearly independent rows.

In this case, the system is consistent since $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A|b)$,

$\;\;\;$and it has infinitely many solutions since 
$\text{nullity}(A)=3-\text{rank}(A)>0$

---

If $\lambda=4$ and $\mu=0$, the system is inconsistent since $\text{rank}(A)=1<2=\text{rank}(A|b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions would be:

1. $dim(Nul(A)) > 0$ Which, in this case, happens with any $\lambda,\mu$ since A is not a square matrix.
2. $\left( ^\lambda_\mu\right) \in Col(A)$. The only way of this not happening is if $d(Col(A)) < 2 $, which, roughly looking at A, seems to only happen if $\mu = 0$ and $\lambda = 4$...